# RequireJS local error callback for timeout ignored

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Any file that is required that does not respond for longer than the wait time breaks the application and does not enter ANY error callback I define.

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 1,
    catchError: {
        define: true
    }
});
require.onError = function() {
    // Does not reach here
};
require(['http://localhost/remote-file-that-does-not-respond-for-more-than-config-wait-time.js'], function() {}, function() {
    // Err callback never triggers
});
```

The app will crash and the console will log:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: remote-scripts!,http://localhost/remote-file-that-does-not-respond-for-more-than-config-wait-time.js http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

Whereas if there is a 404 response, the error callback works just fine:

```
require(['http://localhost/external-file-that-does-not-exist.js'], function() {}, function() {
    // Err callback does trigger
});
```

Why is it that when the server does not respond it won't trigger the local error callback, or even reach the global error callback?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `enforceDefine: true`. Otherwise, RequireJS may fail to detect some timeouts. Documentation [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-enforceDefine).